# Drupal Menu Throws SQL Error

Tags: drupal, drupal-navigation

I have this weird problem with Drupal Menus. When I try to add a link to any drupal menu, it throws the following SQL exception. I can create a new menu or delete an existing one, but I can't add any links :-) Any help?

Additional uncaught exception thrown while handling exception.

Original

PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away: SELECT s.lid, t.translation, s.version FROM {locales_source} s LEFT JOIN {locales_target} t ON s.lid = t.lid AND t.language = :language WHERE s.source = :source AND s.context = :context AND s.textgroup = 'default'; Array ( [:language] => tr [:source] => Configure how content input by users is filtered, including allowed HTML tags. Also allows enabling of module-provided filters. [:context] => ) in locale() (line 684 of /home/predra/public_html/modules/locale/locale.module).

Additional

PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away: INSERT INTO {watchdog} (uid, type, message, variables, severity, link, location, referer, hostname, timestamp) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7, :db_insert_placeholder_8, :db_insert_placeholder_9); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 1 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => php [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => %type: !message in %function (line %line of %file). [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => a:6:{s:5:"%type";s:12:"PDOException";s:8:"!message";s:495:"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away: SELECT s.lid, t.translation, s.version FROM {locales_source} s LEFT JOIN {locales_target} t ON s.lid = t.lid AND t.language = :language WHERE s.source = :source AND s.context = :context AND s.textgroup = &#039;default&#039;; Array ( [:language] =&gt; tr [:source] =&gt; Configure how content input by users is filtered, including allowed HTML tags. Also allows enabling of module-provided filters. [:context] =&gt; ) ";s:9:"%function";s:8:"locale()";s:5:"%file";s:53:"/home/predra/public_html/modules/locale/locale.module";s:5:"%line";i:684;s:14:"severity_level";i:3;} [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 3 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => http://predra.com/admin/structure/menu/manage/menu-header-menu/add [:db_insert_placeholder_7] => http://predra.com/doktor/haldun-san [:db_insert_placeholder_8] => 78.180.179.155 [:db_insert_placeholder_9] => 1348828684 ) in dblog_watchdog() (line 154 of /home/predra/public_html/modules/dblog/dblog.module).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change max_allowed_packet to 20M or more in mysql\bin\my.ini (depends on your mysql server config path.)
It works!